# Symfony validation form of two identical fields

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I use standalone Symfony components in my app (and without Twig).

My HTML form contains two fields ('new_password' & 'confirm_new_password').

The following validation works fine:

```
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$violations = $validator->validate($new_password, [
    new Length(['min' => 4]),
    new Regex([
        'pattern' => '/\d/',
        'match' => true,
        'message' => 'Password must contain at least one number'
    ])
]);

if (0 !== count($violations)) { 
    ...
}
```

I would like to add validation of password confirmation fields as well

The 'Form' component by Symfony allows to create, process and reuse forms, but this is far beyond of what I want to do. I found that 'RepeatedType' field by Symfony can do this but seems to be using the 'Form' component.

How can I simply add password confirmation to my validation script?

Comment: _I would like to add validation of password confirmation fields as well_ **Why?** Just do a check that `$new_password == confirmation password` after you have validated the new password. In fact do that first! :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is indeed possible to do this, but I wanted to implement it as part of the validation offered by Symfony

Comment: Then I think you could add a Class validator instead of a field validator and add a violation to either field (or both) if they are not equal.

Comment: The [repeated type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) is not what you looking for ?

Comment: @CharlieLucas Parent type of this is 'FormType' which I want to avoid using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a constraint call [identicalTo](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/IdenticalTo.html) that looks quite the same as explained by RiggsFolly. So you call this constraint and give it both fields' values.