# Pass object fields to RepeatedType form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have class with user data and i would like to validate it by form.

I have issue with password field.

Field with password in form:

```
add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'first_options'  => ['label' => 'password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat password'],
                'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.'
            ])
```

In model I have two fields:

```
    public string $password;
    public string $passwordRepeat;
```

How to bind model fileds to form field?

Comment: In your Entity, you don't need the `$passwordRepeat` property, just the `$password` property will do. The `RepeatedType` just checks that both the first and second input fields match..

Comment: @Bossman frontend sends the values of the "password" and "repeat password" fields to the API. I would like to check (using form validation) if it is the same.

Comment: You don't need to send both fields. The `RepeatedType` on the form will validate if the user has entered them correctly. If not the message *"The password fields must match."* will be thrown and not submit.. Just remove the `$passwordRepeat` property from your API.

Comment: I don't think you understand me.
I am not using a symfony form.
I send the data from the outside via API.

Comment: You're right, I do not understand you, sorry. You said in your post you are using a form, looks like it is with formBuilder too. Is the API yours?

Comment: I would use form only for validation data. Yes, it's my API

Comment: Anyways, personally it looks like a design issue, but if you really want to do what you are asking then just add 2 `PasswordType` fields, one for `$password` and the other for `$passwordRepeat` instead of the single `ReapeatedType`. This way you can "validate" yourself..

Comment: If you only want to validate an incoming request, you might not need the form system. Look into the `IdenticalTo` constraint, and this somewhat similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73896976/symfony-validation-form-of-two-identical-fields/73904447